# TextView clickable attribute does not work in AlertDialog

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView within an AlertDialog class which I want to make it clickable. I cannot understand what I am missing in my code and the TextView remains unclickable!

The relevant parts from my .java file are as follows (it uses a LayoutInflater):

```
public class LoginDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder{

protected LoginDialog() { 

    TextView reg = (TextView) LoginView.findViewById(R.id.register);
    reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                 Log.i("TAG","Switching to Registration screen");
        }
    });
```

Similarly, the .xml file contains the following:

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register here!"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough when I changed the android:clickable="true" to "false" it worked!

I have not realized why this is happening but I am posting it just in case someone runs into the same issue